# Como executar uma ação quando o scroll alcançar o topo da página?

Tags: jquery, css, rolamento

Tenho todo o código de uma barra lateral fixa que funciona perfeitamente, entretanto quero que assim que a barra de rolagem alcance o início da página, o topo propriamente dito, um elemento receba uma atribuição CSS através do .css().

Algo nessa linha:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
$('#top-tabv2').css({'margin-top': '-1px'});
}
});
```

Como posso proceder?
Desde já, grato! =]

Comment: Seu código parece estar correto. Qual o problema que está dando?

Comment: E está correto, cara! xD Eu não havia percebido isso antes, porque havia dado um erro na compilação e por esse motivo, achei que a falha estava no código, mas, graças a Deus, está tudo funcionando como esperado! Obrigado pelo retorno!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
const execute = function () {
   console.log('Cheguei no topo!');
};

$(window).on('scroll', () => {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() === 0) execute();
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta também, cara! Funciona! =]

Comment: Disponha. Não se esqueça de clicar no ícone de check ao lado esquerdo da minha mensagem para marcar sua questão como resolvida. Dê um voto também. :p